# Overlapping divs in mobile view HTML

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create this design with four identical divs and add a vertical line before image.
[image]

Right now they look like
[image]

But I am facing two problems.

1. I am unable to add a verticla line before image.
2. When I open this view in mobile they are overlapping. How can I avoid this?

Need help!

[image]

Here is my code.

```
                <div  style="border:2px solid #649fc0;padding-right:20px;padding:10px 40px;background:#C5DBE1;width: 350px;border-radius: 25px;"><img height="auto" width="20" src="images/Linux.png"/>Tool for linux is now avialble.</div>
                <br/>
                <div style="border:2px solid #649fc0;float:right;padding: 10px 40px; margin-top:-65px;background: #C5DBE1;width: 350px;border-radius: 25px;"><img height="auto" width="20" src="images/Windows.png"/>Tool for windows is coming soon.</div>
                <br/>
                <div style="border:2px solid #649fc0;padding:10px 40px;background:#C5DBE1;width: 350px;border-radius: 25px;"><img height="auto" width="18" src="images/android_logo_PNG17.png"/>Tool is now avialble for android.</div>
                <br/>
                <div style="border:2px solid #649fc0;float:right;padding: 10px 40px; margin-top:-65px;background:#C5DBE1;width: 350px;border-radius: 25px;"><img height="auto" width="20" src="images/apple.png"/>Tool for IOS is coming soon.</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use inline css :)

Insted of this you can use media queries.
For mobile you just have to 'remove/overwrite' float:right and margin-top: 65px

Here is a quick example for this - https://jsfiddle.net/avfpjyoL/2/

```
.block{
  border:2px solid #649fc0;
  padding:10px 40px;
  background:#C5DBE1;
  max-width: 350px;
  width:100%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.float-right{
  float:right;
}


@media only screen and (max-width :998px) {
  .block{
    background-color: pink;
  }  

.block.float-right{
  float:none;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For your #2 problem, you can write CSS for mobile and other screen resolutions to make your website mobile responsive.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @MikiJay You can avoid inline styling and implement external stylesheet .There you can use media queries for different screen width.

Comment: Basically what Pratyush said. You can either add your mobile CSS in the default CSS file or you can write it in separate sheet and include it in the website.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this can help you on your way:

```
<div style="border:2px solid #649fc0;float:left;padding-right:20px;padding:10px 40px;background:#C5DBE1;width: 350px;border-radius: 25px;margin-bottom: 10px;"><img height="auto" width="20" style="border-right: 1px solid black; padding-right: 10px;" src="images/Linux.png"/>Tool for linux is now avialble.</div>
<div style="border:2px solid #649fc0;float:right;padding: 10px 40px; background: #C5DBE1;width: 350px;border-radius: 25px;margin-bottom: 10px;"><img height="auto" width="20" style="border-right: 1px solid black; padding-right: 10px;" src="images/Windows.png"/>Tool for windows is coming soon.</div>
<div style="border:2px solid #649fc0;float:left; padding:10px 40px;background:#C5DBE1;width: 350px;border-radius: 25px;margin-bottom: 10px;"><img height="auto" width="18" style="border-right: 1px solid black; padding-right: 10px;" src="images/android_logo_PNG17.png"/>Tool is now avialble for android.</div>
<div style="border:2px solid #649fc0;float:right;padding: 10px 40px; background:#C5DBE1;width: 350px;border-radius: 25px;margin-bottom: 10px;"><img height="auto" width="20" style="border-right: 1px solid black; padding-right: 10px;" src="images/apple.png"/>Tool for IOS is coming soon.</div>
```

But as user Pratyush said, you should use Media Queries to get things to show the way you want on smaller screens (you use them in CSS files).